# Ubuntu 16.04 slow connection to iPhone wifi hotspot

Tags: 16.04, wireless, iphone, hot-spot

Connection to my home router wifi is normal. But when I set my iPhone as hotspot. I can rarely connect to it (it is extremely slow even when successfully connected).

The iPhone hotspot setting should have no problem. Because I tried connect to it in Windows 10 and everything is fine. So it should be the problem of Ubuntu.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/300665 and post your results for the wireless script

Comment: @Jeremy31 Thanks! Wireless info output added.

Comment: Can you post results when the phone has hotspot mode on?

Comment: You mean when my pc is connected to my iPhone hotspot?

Comment: That might help, I was just interested in what encryption methods were used by the phone, your home wifi if using the preferred WPA2 only which is also the most secure

Comment: @Jeremy31 Sorry for keeping you wait. I tried many times but now I can't even connect to the iPhone hotspot. Anyway, here is the wireless info run when my pc has wired connection. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please point out which hotspots are the "home router wifi" and the iPhone in question? Thanks. Also, you can use a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) for longer listings and include the link of your pastie in your question.

Comment: @DavidFoerster Lake House is my router wifi, and CHENiPhone is my iPhone hot spot. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than truncating the output from the wireless script (all of which could be relevant) please [edit] a link to a [pastie](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) into your post instead. Thank you for helping us help you!